# Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed - solver vba

Tags: vba

I have written this code, but it starts having an error at the first 'SolverOk' line.  Not sure how to solve and any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
Worksheets("Reconciliation").Activate
Range("AM3").Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:G1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell.Select, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:G1").Select), _
        Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("AN" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select, Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("AO" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select, Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("AP" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select, Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("AQ" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select, Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("AR" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select, Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("AS" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select, Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("AT" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select, Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("AQ" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=Range("AN" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
    SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell.Select, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:G1").Select), _
        Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell.Select, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:G1").Select), _
        Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverSolve
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop
```

Comment: I very much doubt `SetCell:=ActiveCell.Select` is a valid parameter, since `.Select` is a procedure, not a function - it doesn't return anything, it just selects a cell. Does `SolverReset` activate or select anything? Every single `Range` call is implicitly working off the `ActiveSheet`, which makes your code extremely frail. You need to read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513) and pretty much rewrite everything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the `.Select` calls anywhere they appear in an argument you're passing to anything:

```
SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell.Select
```

Should be

```
SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell
```

And

```
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("AN" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
```

Should be

```
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("AN" & (ActiveCell.Row))
```

You want to pass a `Range` object reference; `.Select` doesn't return anything, it *selects* the range, that range becomes the current `Selection` and it does affect the `ActiveCell`, which makes it nearly impossible to track exactly what's being passed to your procedures.

[Avoid .Select and .Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros?noredirect=1&lq=1) and work off object references instead:

```
Dim target As Range
Set target = ActiveCell 'best set it to an actual specific Range on a specific Worksheet.

'now work with it:
SolverOk SetCell:=target, ...
```